# Grid filter doesn´t work with multiples values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datasource, kendo-ui

I have a problem with the filter on this grid:

grid declaration:

```
            >$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "datos/CargarTipo_Impresion_s.php" //php file with mysql sentence
                    },
                    batch: true,
                    schema: {
                        model: 
                            id: "notipoimpresion",
                            fields: 
                                notipoimpresion: { type: "number" },
                                descripcion: { type: "string" },
                                nogrupo: { type: "number" },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    //send notipoimpresion like parameter to the page : CargarTipo_Impresion_s.php
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    //filter: { field: "notipoimpresion", operator: "eq", value: "1,2" }, // with this filter is ok, show data
                    //filter: { field: "notipoimpresion", operator: "eq", value: 2 }, //with this filter is ok , show data
                    //filter: { field: "notipoimpresion", operator: "eq", value: '1,2' }, //with this filter is ok, show data

                    filter: { field: "notipoimpresion", operator: "eq", value: value_codigos_tipo_impresion }, //with this filter doesn´t show data
                    //value_codigos_tipo_impresion, can have this values: "1" or "1,2" or "1,2,4", etc.
                   //value_codigos_tipo_impresion, receive the value from a form text
```

in CargarTipo_Impresion_s.php use this:

> $codigos_tipo_impresion = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["filter"]["filters"][0]["value"]);

and the execute a mysql sentence

In other example with php variable works!

> filter: { field: "notipoimpresion", operator: "eq", value:"?php var_codigos_tipo_impresion; ?" },

when $var_codigos_tipo_impresion: can have values: "1", "1,2", "1,2,3·, etc...

Could someone tell me, why doesn´t make the filter ? or what is wrong?

Thanks
JC

Comment: Put all your codes in code block.

Comment: my codes, ready on code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example and solution: Code corrected and version KendoUI CSS and JavaScript : v2012.3.1114

jsfiddle.net/jcpaquot/vJTwF/6][1]